# Solving L1 regularized Joint Least Squares and Logistic Regression

Tags: convex-optimization, regularization

My objective function that is to be minimized is as follows:

$f = -\sum_{n=1}^{N}log~p(y_{n}^{a}|x_{n},w) + \sum_{n=1}^{N}(y_{n}^{b}-w^{T}x_{n})^{2} +\lambda\|w\|_1$

The first term models the relationship between data $x$ and labels $y^{a}$ using logistic regression, while the second term models data $x$ and labels $y^{b}$ using linear regression. The third term is to enforce sparsity/feature selection.

My question - I found a number of papers that either show how to solve L1 regularized logistic regression or linear regression. However, I could not find any method that could be applied to both kinds of problems. Do there exist techniques that can help me solve the above problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a disclaimer: I'm not sure I see the statistical validity of combining both linear and logistic regression *with the same measurement vectors $x_n$*. I am going to assume you know what you are doing :-) and address the optimization question only.

Some quick and dirty approaches:

- My Matlab toolbox [CVX 2.1](http://cvxr.com/cvx) can handle this, although with [a caveat](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/advanced.html#the-successive-approximation-method) because it has to jump through some hoops to get the underlying solvers to accept the logistic regression term.
- [CVX 3.0 beta](http://cvxr.com/cvx/beta/) coupled with the [SCS solver](https://github.com/cvxgrp/scs) can solve this problem "natively", thus avoiding the aforementioned caveat; but this will be a bit more difficult to get up and running, and again, it's a beta!.
- [YALMIP](http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/) can probably handle this well, too; and I believe it connects to SCS as well, which means it can also solve this problem natively.
- [CVXPY](http://cvxpy.org) coupled with SCS can do this same thing in Python.
- And you can implement your own proximal gradient solver if you are so inclined, though of course that's an advanced approach. You'd have to build a function to compute your own derivatives of the smooth portion of the objective.

[Here](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/examples/cvxbook/Ch07_statistical_estim/html/logistics.html) is a logistic regression example for CVX, so you can see how to express the logistic term in a compliant manner using the CVX function `log_sum_exp`. It's a simple matter to modify this example to add the additional terms.

My recommendation is that you provide weighting values for both the linear regression and $\ell_1$ terms. That is, minimize something like this:
$$f = -\sum_{n=1}^{N}\log~p(y_{n}^{a}|x_{n},w) + \lambda_1\sum_{n=1}^{N}(y_{n}^{b}-w^{T}x_{n})^{2} +\lambda_2\|w\|_1$$
You won't know what the best values of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are until you have done some cross validation. What I  *do* know is that the chance that $\lambda_1=1$ is your best choice is slim to none.

The model in CVX is going to look something like this, and assumes that the data $y^a_n$, $y^b_n$ are stored in column vectors `ya` and `yb`, respectively, and the vectors the columns of the matrix `X`.

```
cvx_begin
    variable w(m)
    minimize(...
        -ya'*X*w+sum(log_sum_exp([zeros(1,m); w'*X'])) ... %logistic
        +lambda1*sum_square(yb-X*w) ... %linear
        +lambda2*norm(w,1)) %regularizer
cvx_end
```

Comment: I wish CVX 3.0 would finish its beta phase one day :-).

Comment: Royi, would you do me a favor and stop bugging me about this? I'm sure you mean well, and I would like to see it finished, too. But I have to pay the bills, and developing CVX, unfortunately, does not do that. I will finish it when I have time.

Comment: No intention bugging you. It was out of appreciation not trying to bug anyone. Sorry for that.

Comment: My apologies for being harsh. But you are a persistent fellow! :-)

Comment: Being consistent is a necessary condition for being lucky. Unfortunately it is not sufficient :-). So I keep trying my luck.